# pandas TypeError when adding column of timnedelta to a column of timestamps

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, shift

I need to shift a column of uneven timestamps by a column of uneven timedeltas. I tried to add the two columns but get an TypeError.

I have one pandas timeseries (timestamps) with a column of the datetime

```
time
2011-01-01 00:00:00+01:00    2011-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
2011-01-01 00:15:00+01:00    2011-01-01 00:15:00+01:00
2011-01-01 00:30:00+01:00    2011-01-01 00:30:00+01:00
```

and another timeseries with delta values (deltas):

```
2011-01-01 00:00:00+01:00   00:15:00
2011-01-01 00:15:00+01:00   00:15:00
2011-01-01 00:30:00+01:00   00:30:00
```

Now I try to add the two by `timestamps.add(deltas)` or `timestamps+deltas`
but both throw the error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not 
be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'
```

Individual calculations are working well: 
`timestamps[1]+deltas[1]`
result in `timestamp('2011-01-01 00:30:00+0100', tz='Europe/Berlin')`

What am I doing wrong? What would be the best way to solve this task?

Comment: Which version of pandas and numpy are you using? For me this seems to work. Or, can you add a small reproducible example (with code to make the two series)?